# How to get a value with the select method on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, page-refresh

I use this method to allow a user to select a date:

```
<%= select( 'resource', 'field', @benchmark.compositions.find(:all).collect {|u| [u.date_composition] }, :prompt => 'Selected date') %>
```

Now I would like to use the date selected (ex: var = '2014-05-05') in a loop to choose the relevant data:

```
<% @benchmark.compositions.where(date_composition: a).each do |compositions| %>
```

I don't know how to store the user's choice and to refresh the page to make the relevant data appear.

Comment: Have you considered ajax to pass selection and lookup the value?

Comment: No, I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: This is a very broad topic, quite popular, and there are plenty of resources in the internet. Please have a look around, and post any specific question that you may have.

Comment: Well, I read several subjects, but I can't answer my question. In fact, i need to get the value on select/change or after submission, and I've been told that I should do it via Coffeescript or JQuery, but I don't know how to implement it. Thank you !!